# Get values of the same column from two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table

```
select id, name from projects;
id |    name     
---+-------------
 1 | TestProject
 2 | testProject
 3 | test
 4 | sdaf
 5 | P0500
```

and this table (work_packages)

```
 select * from work_packages;
 id |  name   | started_on | finished_on | person_month | parent_id | project_id
----+---------+------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+------------+---------
  7 | AP00001 | 2015-10-23 | 2015-10-31  |            0 |         1 |          1 |        
  8 | d       | 2015-10-23 | 2015-10-31  |            0 |         7 |          1 |
```

I need this table from `projects` and `work_packages`

```
name         
---------------
 P0500
 AP00001
 d
```

Comment: I need the last table as answer , I can write for example this :  
    select work_packages.name  from work_packages inner join projects on projects.id = 12; 

and getting 

    name   
    ---------
    AP00001
    d
   (2 rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
select name from projects
union
select name from work_packages;
```

You can filter the result in where condition, e.g.

```
select name from projects
where id >= 5
union
select name from work_packages;
```